# ffmpeg buffer overflow when trying video overlay

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I am trying to overlay a video onto another video by using filter_complex. But it doesn't do overlay properly and says 'Buffer queue overflow'. It works fine if I remove delay by not using -itsoffset. Please let me know what can I do to overcome this problem. I am using latest version of ffmpeg.
It is 2.2 N-62296-g4484152.

Here is the command I am trying.

```
ffmpeg -i .Files/1szqpq/hjmuqD/creation/overlaid-video.mp4 -itsoffset 22.952 -i .Files/1szqpq/hjmuqD/creation/07eda82db409f6c212ffa829287d9c0d_clip.webm -filter_complex "overlay=x='if(gte(t,34.28),NAN,0)':y=0" -y .Files/1szqpq/hjmuqD/creation/overlaid-video-2.mp4
```

And here is the output log.

```
ffmpeg version 2.2-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 24 2014 22:25:11 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Users/tessus/data/ext/ffmpeg/sw --as=yasm --extra-version=tessus --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libspeex --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libxavs --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libgsm --enable-libopus --enable-libmodplug --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-filters --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.Files/1szqpq/hjmuqD/creation/overlaid-video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
  Duration: 00:00:44.91, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 443 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 392 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, matroska,webm, from '.Files/1szqpq/hjmuqD/creation/07eda82db409f6c212ffa829287d9c0d_clip.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.2.0 + libmatroska v1.1.0
    creation_time   : 2014-04-09 06:16:15
  Duration: 00:00:11.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 996 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 274x486, SAR 1:1 DAR 137:243, 30.05 fps, 30.05 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #1:1: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '.Files/1szqpq/hjmuqD/creation/overlaid-video-2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (vp8) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0x103800000] [framesync @ 0x1038000e8] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 624 times
frame= 1345 fps=181 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2130kB time=00:00:44.81 bitrate= 389.4kbits/s dup=624 drop=0    
video:1851kB audio:251kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.348262%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] frame I:8     Avg QP:13.93  size: 30628
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] frame P:402   Avg QP:17.93  size:  2802
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] frame B:935   Avg QP:20.63  size:   560
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] consecutive B-frames:  2.4% 14.4%  1.1% 82.1%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] mb I  I16..4:  9.0% 73.4% 17.6%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] mb P  I16..4:  1.7%  1.7%  0.3%  P16..4: 10.9%  2.3%  0.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:82.2%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  7.6%  0.4%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:91.7%  L0:46.5% L1:50.8% BI: 2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] 8x8 transform intra:53.1% inter:78.0%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 31.4% 36.8% 7.9% inter: 1.1% 2.3% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 31% 27%  7% 35%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 41% 20% 23%  3%  3%  3%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 39% 25% 14%  3%  4%  4%  4%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 74% 12% 11%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] ref P L0: 68.4%  8.7% 17.1%  5.8%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] ref B L0: 85.5% 13.7%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] ref B L1: 97.5%  2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x104000600] kb/s:337.78
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in ffmpeg that was closed as fixed 12 months ago :
[#2467 -itsoffset with overlay filter buffer queue overflow](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2467).

You should ensure that you are using the latest ffmpeg version.
If you are on that version and the problem still occurs,
you should reopen the bug report.

Some workarounds are included in the stackoverflow thread
[FFMPEG - errors when combining videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590221/ffmpeg-errors-when-combining-videos),
which mainly involve using avisynth (Windows) or avxsynth (Linux port of avisynth),
or converting and overlaying the files as x264.

Comment: Same problem as OP, was using old version of ffmpeg. New version worked perfectly.  Couldn't get AviSynth working.