# Overlay two live streams with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine two live stream together similar to this

[image]

I'm following this guide here to replace the videos with a live stream (the live streams are working fine).

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://source.com:554/livecastOne -vf "movie=rtsp://source.com:554/livecastTwo[inner]; [in][inner] overlay=70:70[out]" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f flv rtmp://out.com:1935/outrtmp
```

However it gives me a parse error  does the overlay not work with a 
livestream?

```
[movie @ 0x185baa0] [Eval @ 0x7ffdc71e6ef0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'livecastTwo'
[movie @ 0x185baa0] Unable to parse option value "554/livecastTwo"
[movie @ 0x185baa0] [Eval @ 0x7ffdc71e6f50] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'livecastTwo'
[movie @ 0x185baa0] Unable to parse option value "554/livecastTwo"
[movie @ 0x185baa0] Error setting option stream_index to value 554/livecastTwo.
[Parsed_movie_0 @ 0x1804fe0] Error applying options to the filter.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to ingest both feeds normally.

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://source.com:554/livecastOne" -i "rtsp://source.com:554/livecastTwo"
   -filter_complex "overlay=70:70"
   -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f flv rtmp://out.com:1935/outrtmp
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, It's working, somewhat. I could not get video2 to appear. I get buffer overflow warnings.

Comment: @Robin if you're getting buffer overflow messages, you should consider updating your FFmpeg installation (see https://superuser.com/a/741405/163809) as older versions are known to throw these kinds of errors when overlaying live streams.